# MFC C++: How to actually save a certain file to the system, not just open a save as dialog box

Tags: c++, mfc

I searched everywhere but I can't find sample on how to actually save a file to the system. Threads about opening a Save File dialog box can be read in numerous sites but the successful saving of the user created file to a user selected path is always cut (//add your code here). Please bear with me as I am new in C++ (MFC).

I know I need to actually code the saving of the data to the file path but I just don't know how.

Code snippet (via CFileDialog):

```
void CTryDlg::OnBnClickedSaveAs()
{
    CFileDialog dlg(FALSE);
    dlg.m_ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    dlg.m_ofn.lpstrFilter = _T("Text Files (*.txt)\0*.txt\0All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0\0");
    dlg.m_ofn.lpstrTitle = _T("Save File As");
    CString filename;
    if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        filename = dlg.GetPathName(); // return full path and filename
        //write your sample code here to save the file to the user selected path
    }                                                                                           
}
```

Code snippet via GetSaveFileName():

```
OPENFILENAME SfnInit()
{
    OPENFILENAME t_sfn;

    char szFileName[MAX_PATH] = "";
    ZeroMemory(&t_sfn, sizeof(t_sfn));
    t_sfn.lStructSize = sizeof(t_sfn);
    t_sfn.hwndOwner = NULL;
    t_sfn.lpstrFilter = _T("Text file\0*.txt\0");
    t_sfn.lpstrFile = szFileName;
    t_sfn.lpstrTitle = _T("Save As\0");
    t_sfn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    t_sfn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
    t_sfn.lpstrDefExt = _T("Text file\0*.txt\0");

    if (GetSaveFileName(&t_sfn2) != true)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Saving file canceled!"));
    }
    else
    {
        //write your sample code here to save the file to the user selected path
    }
}
```

Anybody who can provide a very simple sample code that could actually save a user desired file (ex: text file) to the user selected path will be greatly appreciated.
I have also read that the program should run as administrator.

Thank you.

Comment: Running as administrator is only necessary if you're trying to open a file in a protected directory.  You shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: Look up MFC's `CFile` class. It's pretty well documented.

Comment: @jkb I'll check on this. Thanks :)

Comment: There's `std::fstream`, `fopen`, `CFile`, `CreateFile`. And probably some more I forgot about.

Comment: "Newbie" is not an excuse for not knowing something so basic.  My comment was serious.  If you can't write a simple text file from C++, you need a proper class, not a Stackoverflow question.  Surely there's an online tutorial somewhere that would cover it.

Comment: @MarkRansom, "basic" is somewhat subjective. What's basic for you may be hard for others. VC++ has numerous predefined libraries and classes. Some were learned at school but mostly, it can be learned only once encountered. I've been seeing lots of StackOverflow questions that is very elementary for me (but that is my point of view) but mostly those questions are answered very unlikely to yours. God bless you sir.

Comment: Text output is literally one of the first things you will learn in a class, because you will need it to complete your first homework assignment.  That's why I call it "basic".  Stack Overflow is a poor substitute for a class or good book.

Comment: @MarkRansom, sir, this not about coding the text output. I'm asking on how to actually save a file, not write something within a file. I have already come to the point of getting the Save As dialog box (MFC) by using CFileDialog (i preferred this method) and GetSaveFileName(). When i try to click save (after the dialog box open and set a file name), saving is not actually done since threads say actual saving has its own code and that's what I am asking. I asked if anybody could give simple sample code (e.g. saving a .txt file). Thanks anyway for the comments, truly appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using MFC, I would recommend sticking with MFC classes for such file I/O.

Sadly, I am using VS 2008, but here is the class hierarchy for CFile:

[image]

If it's a text file, using/deriving from CStdioFile makes sense.  It has the basic ReadString WriteString methods.

However, if you are wanting to serialize something derived from CDocument (Document/View architecture), you will want to utilize streams, possibly with schemas/versioning to go with your serialization.  That's a completely different topic/answer.

EDIT: duh - here's a simple CStdioFile output

```
        CFileDialog fd(FALSE, "txt", "MyFile.txt", OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*", this);
        if (fd.DoModal() == IDOK)
            {
            CStdioFile fOut(fd.GetPathName(), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite);
            for (int i = 0; i < asData.GetSize(); i++)
                {
                fOut.WriteString(asData[i] + '\n');
                }
            fOut.Close();
            }
```

Comment: I don't share your recommendation (I'd prefer the standard functions), but I do recognize the subjectivity in recommendations.  This code will probably work (depends on the directory chosen of course)

Comment: @MSalters  Yes, the ctor can definitely throw an exception due to invalid/permissions folder, etc.  There are other ways to open the file using more traditional mechanisms (e.g. a failed fOut.Open call instead of throwing an exception in the ctor).

Comment: @franji1, may I ask what and what for is asData[]? Thanks :)

Comment: @Jay_Abitona `asData` is the data you want to write to the file. This is just an example of what could be done. We have no idea what data you need to write to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic sample:

```
...
if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    filename = dlg.GetPathName(); // return full path and filename

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "w");    // open file for writing

    if (file == NULL)
      AfxMessageBox("File couild not be created."};
    else
    {
      // file could be created, write something
      fprintf(file, "Some text\n");

      // and close the file
      fclose(file);
    }
}
...
```

This will write "some text" into the file whose name has been provided by the user with the CFileDialog file picker.

In real world you need to write whatever text according to the data of your program.

This is really most basic knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for this. It worked but I need to turn off the warning for a specific line of code and used the warning pragma, #pragma warning(suppress : 4996).

Comment: @Jay_Abitona lots of very old functions are deprecated, even though they're still useful.  `fprintf` is a holdover from C and is very old indeed.  You might be better served by using the [Stream I/O functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) of C++ even though they're more complicated.